# Break Tablix Rows in the same page(tablix with too many rows)side by side

Tags: ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

i have a table with too many rows in my report(SSRS)
i want to break it into 2 part (split rows)in the **"same page"** 
 side by side - same columns and same header

Answer (score 0):

IF you do not change your report structure.
It seems only available in the print layout via set the columns as 2 in the report property ReportName->Columns->Columns.
And it only displayed in the print layout view. (also mind the width)
see:
[set the newspaper format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDOve.png)
[preview screen shot in print layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhwO5.png)